# How to restore old character names after account reactivation

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've been inactive in WoW for several years. I just renewed my subscription to find that all my character names have been mangled. Presumably, this was done by Blizzard to free up the names for other players that might want to use them.

I would like to restore the old names. To the best of my knowledge, the names I used to use are still available on the realms I used to play in.

I understand Blizzard provides a paid name change service, but I have some fifteen characters on my old account, and that's a substantial amount of money. Are there any other options for returning players?

Comment: If your characters have been renamed by Blizzard they should already be eligible for a name change without having to pay for it. Have you tried logging in to the characters, which have been renamed without your consent?

Comment: @dly I hadn't, but now I have, and I have all my names back. You'd think that would be documented somewhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a character's name has been changed by Blizzard - for violating naming policies, due to inactivity, or because it became a duplicate due to server transfers or undeletion - you will be prompted to enter a new name when you try to log into that character. If their old name is available, you can reclaim it; if it isn't, you will need to pick another one.

Comment: Thank you. It was just a matter of logging in with all of them. You'd think that would be documented *somewhere*, but it's not...

Answer (score 0):

As I know, if the name was given to another character, you can't reclaim it back. So, here no answer for your question. Even if you contact them I think they don't reclaim names to you. So, here is the only way: buy [Blizzard name change service](https://us.shop.battle.net/en-us/product/world-of-warcraft-service-name-change).
Yeah, it costs 10$, but I don't see another way.
Good luck!